# Creating customer service Calendar in D365 via PowerShell command

Tags: powershell, dynamics-crm

*I want to create "customer service Calendar" in D365 via PowerShell command. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance
I have tried something like this, can able to create calendar not calendarurle*

```
$usercalendarid="4385DF09-D156-4D4E-BABE-E6548DF50B49"
$StandardBUid ="BCAF91CC-5D73-EA11-A811-000D3AB855E7"
$mainCalendarGuid="4385DF09-D156-4D4E-BABE-E6548DF50B49"
$innerCalendarGuid="9566ab3e-208f-40cb-9b01-35110efa1161"
$businessunit = Get-CrmRecord -conn $conn -EntityLogicalName businessunit -Id $StandardBUid -Fields name 
$standardBUReference = New-CrmEntityReference -EntityLogicalName businessunit -Id $StandardBUid  
$calendarTypeValue = New-Object -TypeName  Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue -ArgumentList 1
$calendarid = New-Object -TypeName  System.Guid $mainCalendarGuid
New-CrmRecord -conn $conn -EntityLogicalName calendar -Fields @{"name"="cale2";"type"=$calendarTypeValue;"businessunitid"=$standardBUReference;calendarid=$calendarid } 

*-- Create innercalendar*  
$innerscalendarid = New-Object -TypeName  System.Guid $innerCalendarGuid
$calendarTypeValue = New-Object -TypeName  Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue -ArgumentList -1
New-CrmRecord -conn $conn -EntityLogicalName calendar -Fields @{"name"="inner";"businessunitid"=$standardBUReference; calendarid=$innerscalendarid } 

-- Create calendarrule
$createdInnerCalendarReference = New-CrmEntityReference -EntityLogicalName calendar -Id $innerCalendarGuid
$createdMainCalendarReference = New-CrmEntityReference -EntityLogicalName calendar -Id $mainCalendarGuid
$timezoneValue = New-Object -TypeName  Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue -ArgumentList 190
$entCollectioncalendarRules = New-Object Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityCollection
[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity]$calendarRuleEntity = New-Object Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity
$calendarRuleEntity.LogicalName = 'calendarrule' 
$calendarRuleEntity.Id= New-Object -TypeName  System.Guid '9d3423b2-c69e-46db-9fde-b7f68784286c' 
$calendarRuleEntity.Attributes['duration']=1234
$calendarRuleEntity.Attributes['calendarid']=$createdMainCalendarReference 
$calendarRuleEntity.Attributes['innercalendarid']=$createdInnerCalendarReference 
$calendarRuleEntity.Attributes['effort']=1.0;
$calendarRuleEntity.Attributes['extentcode']=1;
$calendarRuleEntity.Attributes['pattern'] = "FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=1"
$calendarRuleEntity.Attributes['rank']=0
$calendarRuleEntity.Attributes['timezonecode']=110
$calendarRuleEntity.Attributes['starttime'] = Get-Date
$calendarRuleEntity.Attributes['innercalendarid'] =$createdInnerCalendarReference 
$calendarRuleEntity.Attributes['calendarid'] = $createdMainCalendarReference
$entCollectioncalendarRules.Entities.Add($calendarRuleEntity)  
$entCollectioncalendarRules.Entities.Add($calendarRuleEntity1)   
-- Update Calendarrule to calendar  
$calendartobeUpdated = Get-CrmRecord -conn $conn -EntityLogicalName calendar -Id $innerCalendarGuid -Fields * 
$calendartobeUpdated.name="Updated from powershell 2"
$calendartobeUpdated.calendarrules.Entities.Add($calendarRuleEntity) 
Set-CrmRecord -conn $conn -CrmRecord $calendartobeUpdated
```

Comment: Did you try something?